# Question about controlling the documentation of enumerations in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I’m using Doxygen to document a C++ library. Documentation of enumerations is not nearly as helpful as it might be, and I can’t find anything about controlling the output. The generated output puts an undocumented version of the enumeration at the top of the namespace page in an "Enumerations" section, individual elements of which link to the actual useful documentation, under an Enumeration Type Documentation section. In a real example, there may be many of these undocumented enumerations before the page gets around to the Enumeration Type Documentation section where the useful help documenting the use of each value can be found.

How can I suppress the Enumerations section entirely, while leaving the Enumeration Type Documentation section that actually documents the enumeration values?

[image: Example documentation output]

The output is generated from this example .h file:

```
//! \file
#pragma once

//! \brief My main namespace
namespace MyNamespace
{
    //! \brief An example enumeration with the useful values documented.
    enum class MyExampleEnum
    {
        UNKNOWN,

        FirstValue,     //!< This is the useful documentation
        SecondValue,    //!< This is useful documentation of SecondValue

        COUNT,
    };
}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear, for me, what you want. Maybe a small example plus images with how it is now and (draw on it) what you would like might help. Maybe the chapter about customizing the output in the manual (http://doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) can be of help. Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Added an image to the question with example output. To my mind, the top section is completely useless, and I'd like to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, albert. Customization of the layout file addresses my issue.